# Elementary Corrupted iso downloads

Tags: software-installation

Sent to contact@Elementary.io :
I bought elementary last August.
I've been trying to install it since then with no avail.
Every single download is corrupted. Unable to use.
No need to tell about messages from google accusing for doing illegal stuff...
What a drag,

Reply : The response was:

Your email to group press@elementaryos.org was rejected due to spam classification. The owner of the group can choose to enable message moderation instead of bouncing these emails. More information can be found here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/168383.

Comment: HI! What do you mean by corrupted? Are you having issues creating a bootable USB drive?

Comment: MDA mode2 WDC (stealing mode?): no option to change this mode;

Comment: desktop who knows where? No download whatsoever on desktop. 5 Kworkers(?)

Comment: Init. line 49 : 5.0.0.0 no medium found

Comment: Is  /casper/vmlinuz supposed to be in my boot usb key?